# How would I find and then send an email to all of the emails in my inbox in Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

I’m trying to make a GMail subscription service with Google Apps Script. I want it to send an email to every single email in my inbox. How would I do this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask], [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks), [mcve] and [Learn More](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function replyToInboxMessages() {
  const threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads();
  threads.forEach(t => {
    t.getMessages().forEach(m =>{
      GmailApp.sendEmail(m.getFrom(),'Return Email','Quit Sending us Email');
    });
  });
}
```